# issue with ajax populating database and displaying results in an html table

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have orders table in my database that has id,name and status columns.Then i have html table representing my orders table and inside i have
buttons that i want to update the status column using ajax to make it asynchronous displaying the changes in the html table rigth away.How can i 
achieve this?I have tried running ajax functions onclick of a button passing order id as an argument and then using get method to fetch the result but
something is wrong with the document.getElementsByClassName method it is not populating my status field in the html table nor the database is being changed.

orders.php

```
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT*FROM orders");
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<th>Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Status</th><th>Considering</th><th>Accepted</th>";

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
$id=$row['id'];
$name=$row['name'];
$status=$row['status'];
echo "<tr>
<td>$id</td><td>$name</td><td><div class='status'>$status</div></td><td><buttton onclick=\"considering('$id')\">Considering</button></td>
<td><buttton onclick=\"accepted('$id')\">Accepted</button></td>
</tr>";
}
```

admin.php

```
<?php
include "include/connect.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function considering(one){
var a=new XMLHttpRequest();
a.open("GET","considering_parser.php?one="+one,true);
    a.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(a.readyState==4 && a.status==200){
        var returndata=a.responseText;
        var x=document.getElementsByClassName("status");
        for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        x[i].innerHTML=returndata;
        }
        }
    }
    a.send(null);
}
function accepted(two){
var b=new XMLHttpRequest();
b.open("GET","accepted_parser.php?two="+two,true);
    b.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(b.readyState==4 && b.status==200){
        var returndata=b.responseText;
        var x=document.getElementsByClassName("status");
        for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        x[i].innerHTML=returndata;
        }
        }
        }

    b.send(null);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<?php
include "orders.php";
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

considering_parser.php

```
<?php
include "include/connect.php";

$id=$_GET['one'];
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE orders SET status=1 WHERE id='$id'");
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id='$id'");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
$one=$row['status'];
echo $one;
}

?>
```

accepted_parser.php

```
<?php
include "include/connect.php";

$id=$_GET['two'];
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE orders SET status=2 WHERE id='$id'");
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id='$id'");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
$two=$row['status'];
echo $two;
}

?>
```

Help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console to see if there are any errors?

Comment: You need to use [`multi_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) for `accepted_parser.php` and `considering_parser.php` since you're overwriting the first.

Comment: *...meaning that,* only the last queries will be executed. The first one(s) will be ignored.

Comment: @Fred-ii- could you please write the code i am a bit confused i have never used  multy_query() before

Comment: The function I left you above, is a clickable link to the function, being http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- ok i used multi_queries on both files.Here is my accepted_parser.php..<?php
include "include/connect.php";

$id=$_GET['one'];
$query="UPDATE orders SET status=1 WHERE id='$id';
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id='$id';";
if (mysqli_multi_query($conn,$query))
{
  do
    {
    // Store first result set
    if ($result=mysqli_store_result($conn))
      {
      while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        $one=$row['status'];
  echo $one;
        }
      mysqli_free_result($conn);
      }
    }
  while (mysqli_more_results($conn));
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?> now it is not async

Comment: my html table is not being updated asynchronously and i get a fatal error of maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved it thanks to Fred-ii's suggestion to use multi_query()

orders.php

```
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT*FROM orders");
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<th>Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Status</th><th>Considering</th><th>Accepted</th>";

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
$id=$row['id'];
$name=$row['name'];
$status=$row['status'];
echo "<tr>
<td>$id</td><td>$name</td><td><div class='status$id'>$status</div></td><td><buttton onclick=\"considering('$id')\">Considering</button></td>
<td><buttton onclick=\"accepted('$id')\">Accepted</button></td>
</tr>";
}
```

admin.php

```
 <html>
<head>
<script>
function considering(one){
var a=new XMLHttpRequest();
a.open("GET","considering_parser.php?one="+one,true);
    a.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(a.readyState==4 && a.status==200){
        var returndata=a.responseText;
        var x=document.getElementsByClassName("status"+one);
        for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        x[i].innerHTML=returndata;
        }
        }
    }
    a.send(null);
}
function accepted(two){
var b=new XMLHttpRequest();
b.open("GET","accepted_parser.php?two="+two,true);
    b.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(b.readyState==4 && b.status==200){
        var returndata=b.responseText;
        var x=document.getElementsByClassName("status"+two);
        for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        x[i].innerHTML=returndata;
        }
        }
        }

    b.send(null);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<?php
include "orders.php";
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

considering_parser.php

```
<?php
include "include/connect.php";

$id=$_GET['jedan'];
$query="UPDATE orders SET status=1 WHERE id='$id';
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id='$id';";
if (mysqli_multi_query($conn,$query))
{
  do
    {
    // Store first result set
    if ($result=mysqli_store_result($conn))
      {
      while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        $one=$row['status'];
        echo $one;
        }

      }
    }
  while (mysqli_more_results($conn) && mysqli_next_result($conn));
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Similar code for the accepted_parser.php.Thank you Fred-ii